# Decorative hook or symbol before chapter (or section) title

Tags: chapters, sections-paragraphs, decorations

I'm writing my PhD thesis in latex and learned a lot from this forum. However, I could not find an answer to the question how do I put an decorative hook before the chapter title.
I think that it looks rather nice to have this but thats personal.

Comment: Answering your own question is perfectly fine here!  However, please put the answer _in an answer_ and not edited in to the original question.  Otherwise, it's hard for others to learn from as it is confusing.  And others might have other answers but without a clear question then it's hard to figure out what the question is.

Comment: I moved your solution the answer space below, where it belongs.

Answer (score 2):

*Solution by Sander van Delden given in the question. I moved it to an answer.*

---

Maybe I was too quick asking this question, but I think I found an answer. Since it is nowhere on the web (I searched for this a few month ago), I will put a minimal working example below for people that might want to have a decoration before their chapter title.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt,twoside]{book} % title page, draft - warning draft turns off hyperref fleqn = left alignment of equantion flushleft
\usepackage{titlesec} %you can set the layout of the chapter title with this one

%-----this creates a decorative hook (picture) that can be put before the capter-----------------
\newcommand{\hook}{
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\linethickness{.4mm} % linethickness of next line
\put(0,-2){\line(0,10){8}} % horizontal line(vector x, vector y){length} were length is in unitlength (in this case mm)  \put(vector x, vector y) this puts the line -2 mm below startpoint 
\linethickness{.6mm} % linethickness of next line
\put(0,-2){\line(10,0){6}} % vertical line(vector x, vector y){length} were length is in unitlength (in this case mm) \put(vector x, vector y) this puts the line -2 mm below startpoint 
\end{picture}
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\huge}{}{1em}{\hook} %\titleformat{ command }[ shape ]{ format }{ label }{ sep }{ before }[ after ] see package titlesec for more info
\titlespacing{\chapter}{6mm}{1pt}{12mm} %\titlespacing{ command }{ left }{ beforesep }{ aftersep }[ right ] see package titlesec for more info

\chapter{Funding}

\end{document}
```

### Result:

[image: Compiled result]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to look further than just a "hook" before the chaper title look at the examples of [Vincent Zoonekynd](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/) for the normal book class.  Lars Madsen has compiled some nice examples for memoir: [MemoirChapStyles](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/MemoirChapStyles).  There is even one with TikZ by Stefan Kottwitz on[TeXblog](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/fancy-chapter-tikz/)