# How can I have a symbol before every chapter/section/subsection title?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, symbols, chapters

How can I have a symbol before the title of each chapter, section and subsection? If possible, I would like to have this symbol in the left margin. The symbol is not important.

This is my MWE:

```
    \documentclass[fancy,12pt,a4paper,oneside,table]{memoir}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    
    \definecolor{sectioncolour}{RGB}{247,131,53}
    \definecolor{chaptercolour}{RGB}{23,85,142}
    \definecolor{subsectioncolour}{RGB}{5,130,34}
    
    \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\large\sffamily\scshape\center\color{chaptercolour}}
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\color{chaptercolour}}
    \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\center\color{chaptercolour}}
    \setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\color{sectioncolour}}
    \setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\sffamily\color{subsectioncolour}}
    
    \begin{document}
        \chapter{Guide Intro}
        \lipsum[1]
        \section{Operations}
        \lipsum[2]
        \section{General view}
        \lipsum[3]
        \subsection{General view}
        \lipsum[4]
        
        \chapter{Guide: Detailed content}
        \lipsum[4]
    
        \chapter{Future}
        \lipsum[5]
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Have you seen this entry? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16142/decorative-hook-or-symbol-before-chapter-or-section-title

Comment: @Ingmar I've read thanks to you. I will study it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you requested this puts a symbol in the left margin before chapter and sectional titles.

```
% symdivprob.tex  SE 639496  (Symbol before divisions)

\documentclass[fancy,12pt,a4paper,oneside,table]{memoir}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    
    \definecolor{sectioncolour}{RGB}{247,131,53}
    \definecolor{chaptercolour}{RGB}{23,85,142}
    \definecolor{subsectioncolour}{RGB}{5,130,34}
    
%%%% PW symbol stuff
    \newcommand{\symdiv}{$\clubsuit$}
    \newcommand{\lsymdiv}{\llap \symdiv}
    \let\saveprintchaptitle\printchaptertitle
    \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\llap\symdiv #1}
    
    \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\large\sffamily\scshape\center\color{chaptercolour}}
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\color{chaptercolour}}
    \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\center\color{chaptercolour}}
    \setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\color{sectioncolour}\lsymdiv}
    \setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\sffamily\color{subsectioncolour}\lsymdiv}
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{Guide Intro}
        \lipsum[2]
        \section{Operations}
        %        \lipsum[2]
        Just a little bit of text. Just a little bit of text.
        Just a little bit of text. Just a little bit of text.
        Just a little bit of text. Just a little bit of text. 
        \subsection{General view}
        Just a little bit more of text. Just a little bit more of text.
        Just a little bit more of text. Just a little bit more of text.
        Just a little bit more of text. Just a little bit more of text. 

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now, it's my turn to study and understand your code.